# Format the average price to 2 decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average, min

Can't figure out how to use SQL Server’s functions to format the average price in Query to money/currency (2 decimal places with a dollar sign)

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT AVG(devMarketCap) AS 'Average Market Cap', 
       MIN(devMarketCap) AS 'Lowest Market Cap',
       MAX(devMarketCap) AS 'Highest Market Cap'
FROM developer INNER JOIN GAME
ON developer.devID = GAME.devID
WHERE devCountry = 'USA' AND gameGenre = 'Fantasy';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT format(AVG(devMarketCap), 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Average Market Cap', 
       format(MIN(devMarketCap), 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Lowest Market Cap',
       format(MAX(devMarketCap), 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Highest Market Cap'
FROM developer INNER JOIN GAME
ON developer.devID = GAME.devID
WHERE devCountry = 'USA' AND gameGenre = 'Fantasy';
```

Other formatting options:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx